# iOS Bonjour Swift 3 search never stops

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, service, bonjour

I'm using the **NetServiceBrowser** for search services actived in my current network, but I have a problem. When the services are actived, the service found these correctly and stop the search but in the other case, when no found any services the **NetServiceBrowser** never stop search. Can I call search method with a timeout?

The code:

```
var _netServiceBrowser : NetServiceBrowser?
self._netServiceBrowser = NetServiceBrowser()
self._netServiceBrowser?.delegate = self
self._netServiceBrowser?.searchForServices(ofType:"_http._tcp", inDomain:"local.")
//...
//TODO
//...
self._netServiceBrowser.stop()
```

And when receive all data I stop the **NetServiceBrowser**, but if not detect any service never call any callback, for that I cant stop this

Thanks :)

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution for that, I included a delay function

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}


delay(2.0, closure: {self._netServiceBrowser.stop()})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that, I included a delay function

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}


delay(2.0, closure: {self._netServiceBrowser.stop()})
```

I added this at the end of the question